# AWS Replication agent problem when launching

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to launch aws replication agent in a CENTOS 8.3 and always returns me an error during the process of replication agent installation ( python3 aws-replication-installer-init.py ......)
The output of the process shows me:

```
The installation of the AWS Replication Agent has started.
Identifying volumes for replication.
Identified volume for replication: /dev/sdb of size 7 GiB
Identified volume for replication: /dev/sda of size 11 GiB
All volumes for replication were successfully identified.
Downloading the AWS Replication Agent onto the source server... Finished.
Installing the AWS Replication Agent onto the source server...
Error: Failed Installing the AWS Replication Agent
Installation failed.
```

If i check the aws_replication_agent_installer.log i can see that appears messages like:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64/build M=/tmp/tmp8mdbz3st/AgentDriver modules
.....................
retcode: 0
Build essentials returned with code None
--- Building software
running: 'which zypper'
retcode: 256
running: 'make'
retcode: 0
running: 'chmod 0770 ./aws-replication-driver-commander'
retcode: 0
running: '/sbin/rmmod aws-replication-driver'
retcode: 256
running: '/sbin/insmod ./aws-replication-driver.ko'
retcode: 256
running: '/sbin/rmmod aws-replication-driver'
retcode: 256
Cannot insert module. Try 0.
running: '/sbin/rmmod aws-replication-driver'
retcode: 256
running: '/sbin/insmod ./aws-replication-driver.ko'
retcode: 256
running: '/sbin/rmmod aws-replication-driver'
retcode: 256
Cannot insert module. Try 1.
............
Cannot insert module. Try 9.
Installation returned with code 2
Installation failed due to unspecified error:

stderr: sh: /var/lib/aws-replication-agent/stopAgent.sh: No such file or directory
which: no zypper in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin)
which: no apt-get in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin)
which: no zypper in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin)
rmmod: ERROR: Module aws_replication_driver is not currently loaded
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ./aws-replication-driver.ko: Required key not available
rmmod: ERROR: Module aws_replication_driver is not currently loaded
```

Any issue of the error?

Answer (score 0):

Launching with the command:

```
mokutil --disable-validation
```

will allow to change kernel modules (next boot will confirm it introducing password that must be entered afet command mokutil)